# Responsive table and image issue

Tags: css, image, responsive, ckeditor5

When we create content in CKEditor 5, the content (e.g. tables and images) is responsive. When we display the HTML output from the editor on a screen, the content is not responsive. What do we need to do to make the content responsive to our users?

Comment: You need to share your html and css ?

Answer (score 0):

use media query to make your content good on different width and height..